# PHP как вложить один элемент в другой

Tags: php, yii2

Есть вот такая кнопка

```js
<?= Html::button(Yii::t('app', 'Buy'), ['class' => 'btn btn_buy', 'id' => 'add_to_basket_buy', 'value' => $ma['id']]) ?>
```

и нужно в нее положить вот эту ссылку

```js
<?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Buy'), ['/additional-service?service_id='.$c->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-collor']) ?>
```

помогите плиз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
<?= Html::a('label', ['/controller/action'], ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

Или использовать **Merge**:

```
<?= Html::button('Press me!', ArrayHelper::merge(['value'=>Url::to(['controller/action'])], ['additionalOptions'])); ?>
```

Предоставлен шаблон, значения самостоятельно подставьте. Подробнее можно глянуть в [источнике](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27401047/yii2-button-with-link).